# Linux: Recv randomly returns zero

Tags: linux, tcp, recv, epoll

I wrote a simple TCP network library with `epoll` for linux.

In one of my tests, I want to test the throughput of the library.
I send 2000000 msgs of 500 bytes.

The binded socket randomly returns zero on a `recv` after 800000 or more msgs have been received.

Other times, all messages are received. What would cause this to happen?

The recv call is at line 393 of the `sparrow.c` file.
I can verify that `data_in->len > data_in->cur`

```
    int result = recv(sock->fd, data_in->data + data_in->cur, data_in->len - data_in->cur, 0);

    //On error or connection closed.
    //TODO We need to handle closed connections differently, possibly automatically reconnecting.
    if(result <= 0) {
      //TODO Make Dprintf
      printf("Receive error or we received a signal that the connection closed.\nWe are closing the connection.\n");
      spev->error = 1;
      sparrow_socket_close(sp,sock);
      return 0;
    }
```

You can check the library here:

1. https://github.com/xekoukou/sparrow
2. https://github.com/xekoukou/sparrow/blob/master/thr_client.c
3. https://github.com/xekoukou/sparrow/blob/master/thr_server.c

edit:

1. I found the problems of the code. First there was a small part of the code that didn't check for EAGAIN error. My code simply closed the connection because it considered it a non-recovering error.
2. @EJP effectively answered the question. Recv returns zero only if the connection is closed or we have a zero sized buffer.
3. Another interesting question is how to effectively debug when something happens in a loop on the 800000 iteration.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't read your whole source code; where's the important, the `sparrow_recv` method? Please include the critical code in your question.

Comment: I pointed the location of the recv call. Hope it helps. sparrow_recv simply gives the input buffer to sparrow. Recv is inside _sparrow_wait.

Comment: `recv()` returns zero at end of stream, which in turn occurs when the peer closes the connection. There is nothing 'random' about it,

Comment: Where is the message code? You've not shown us any code that does anything with messages. The bug is likely in the messaging layer. (Presumably the code that calls this code or the previous few and next few lines.)

Comment: I think that @EJP answered my question. I wanted to exclude the possibility that linux was simply overloaded with messages and decided on its own to close the connection. If you make it an answer I would accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`recv()` returns zero at end of stream, which in turn occurs when the peer closes the connection. There is nothing 'random' about it.